# How to use select database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Code:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $choose_db = mysql_select_db("tablenews",$con);

    $show = mysql_query("select * from table where Genre='school life'");
    $isi = mysql_fetch_array($show);

    echo $isi['title']; 

?>
```

I make this php code, and i have 3 films title with: `Genre='school life'` in my phpmyadmin table news database.

But why my browser just echoing the first film title with `Genre='school life'`? (the second and the third tittle didn't appear).

I want all the three title appear in my website.
Thanks for your responds, any responds will be very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call mysql_fetch_array for EACH row in the query, since it only returns one row each time it's called. Each successive call will return the next row, until there are no more rows and then it will return false. So you can create a loop as per xdazz's answer (i can't upvote yet or I would)
(By the way, mysql anything in php is deprecated and unless you're using an old version of php for some reason you should be using mysqli_fetch_array instead)

http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 3):

You need a loop:

```
while($isi = mysql_fetch_array($show)) {
    echo $isi['title']; 
}
```

Comment: @BuddhistBeast The op said `i have 3 films title with Genre='school life'`

Comment: @BuddhistBeast no. As OP stated, "i have 3 films title with Genre='school life' in my phpadmin tablenews database".

Comment: thanks all for the answers, and it worked, im newbie and sorry if im waste your time, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `mysql_fetch_array` fetches one row at a time, and you call that function only once. To fetch all rows from resylt set, you have to call `mysql_fetch_array` until it returns false value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$choose_db = mysql_select_db("tablenews",$con);
$show=mysql_query("select * from table where Genre='school life'");
while($isi=mysql_fetch_array($show);){
    echo $isi['title']; 
}
?>
```

The issue is echo is going to only give you the first result when used with out the loop. use it as the above mentioned to get all the values which have been fetched